# What Ruby-based blogging systems are there with ready-to-use themes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, blogs, blog-engine

I'm looking for a substitute for Wordpress and Squarespace that's implemented in Ruby. It can be a Rails app, a Rails plugin, or a standalone static page generator. The most important features we're looking for is that it comes with a selection of nice looking themes and is easy to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Typo](http://blog.typosphere.org/) in the past with success. It's written in Ruby, is reasonably active and can be installed as a gem. It comes with a default theme and there are a bucket full of themes available at [Typogarden](http://typogarden.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The most popular weblog engine written in ruby from its earlier days is tdiary ([github](https://github.com/tdiary/tdiary-contrib), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdiary/)). It is developed in Japanese, and there is not much English documentation, though. But there is an English mailing list.